# What is the best way of handling multiple wordings of a question?

Tags: discussion, questions

So if I have multiple ways to phrase a question, What should I do to make it more visible in searches?

For example, All of these are the same question, but using different search terms

- How do I create an index for all nodes in Cypher?
- How can I create an index without using labels in Cypher?
- How can I index nodes without labels using Cypher?
- How do I create a global index using Cypher?

They all ask "How do I create an index for all nodes in Cypher?", but the only thing they have in common is "How ... I ... Index ... Cypher?",  which is a different question.

How can I help make the question more visible to people who don't know how to word the question? (or should I leave that to "close as duplicate" questions other people write?)

I'm thinking something like `How do I create a global index for all nodes without using labels in Cypher`, but that is rather long, and I don't know if any of the examples would pick that up.

**So what is the best way of handling multiple wordings of a question?**

(This question could be `How to handle alternative question names?`!)

Comment: I imagine I'd pick the best one (or one w/ the best answer more likely) and then close the rest as duplicates since this is precisely what that feature is for.

Comment: @CollinD I was kinda hoping there would be a way to preemptively prevent the duplicates by somehow asking the question better. But I guess a short, clear question would probably get better answers.

Comment: This is one of the purposes of the duplicate system: to crowd-source finding the problem description with the most Google juice. Don't overthink it. But do get rid of the "How [can|do] I" bit; it's wasted words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just write the question out using whichever you feel is personally the clearest or most preferable for you personally.  If it turns out that other people end up putting another variation of the question, and search engines aren't able to tell that they're the same (keep in mind that search engines can be quite good at stuff like this; it is their job after all, so there's a good shot that it'd match the search and the question up all on its own) then it would mean someone would ask a duplicate question.  The question can then be closed as a duplicate and, from then on, either variation of the question can be searched on and directed to the canonical answer.

Don't try to spend a bunch of time trying to word your question in a way as to include a bunch of additional keywords that don't naturally fit into the question.  The additional keywords can also be used in the body of the question, as appropriate.  Trying to fit as many keywords into a title as possible is likely to make a question *less* clear.  Instead focus on ensuring that reading the actual title has the highest probability of having that reader understand what the question is about; leave the rest to the body, and to Google.